# Question about the unknot and grid in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: graph-theory, knot-theory

Consider the grid of $\Bbb R^3$ that passes through the points of $\Bbb Z^3$:

$$\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3:\text{ at least two of }x,y,z\text{ are integers}\}.$$

My question is if it is possible to embed the unknot into this grid so that the three product projections $\Bbb R^3\rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ are graphs with no cycles, i.e., trees.

I've only found embeddings where only two of the three projections are trees, so this might be false, but I still don't know.

Any hint or ideas are really appreciated.

Comment: Is "product projection" a standard term for "projection onto coordinate planes"?

Comment: @anon Categorical products come with projectors, for example $\pi_i:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ for $i=1,2,3$.  I've never heard "product projection" before, but in context it must mean a certain kind of product of these projectors.  The $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is what disambiguates it as projections onto coordinate *planes*.  I suppose the identity map $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is also a product projection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This puzzle appeared in *Mathematical Mind-Benders*, by Peter Winkler, a collection of the interesting mathematical puzzles. Your puzzle (without the grid restriction) was in the chapter "Severe Challenges," and most of the puzzles were hard enough already! There is an excellent discussion of the history of the problem in that book, and also in the introduction of paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.02355.pdf.

Anyways, here is the simplest solution, which appears on the cover of the Winkler book.

[image]

Even more interesting, [this blog](https://cp4space.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/treefoil/) gives a solution where the embedding is a trefoil knot:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any idea whether every knot or link can be represented in this way?

Comment: No idea! Figuring out how to do the unknot took about a year, and the creator of the trefoil described it as "miraculous," so I imagine its pretty hard to come up with more complicated knots.

Comment: Damn!, this was harder than I expected, thanks.